# How is fillPattern from a temporary canvas supposed to work?

Tags: javascript, canvas

This code used to work and should still work, but it stopped working on Desktop Chrome. Still works on Mobile Android. This is taking a hidden img element from the document as a texture and drawing some text with it. When I try recoloring it using a new canvas to create a pattern, it fails to fill text.

`

```
var fillPattern = null;
if (fontSettings.fill.recolor != '' && !IExplorerAgent && !operaAgent) {
    var c2 = document.createElement('canvas');
    c2.height = this.fillImage.height / pixelRatio;
    c2.width = this.fillImage.width / pixelRatio;
    var c2Ctx = c2.getContext('2d');                
    c2Ctx.drawImage(this.fillImage,0,0,c2.width,c2.height);
    c2Ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'color';
    c2Ctx.fillStyle = fontSettings.fill.recolor;
    c2Ctx.fillRect(0,0,c2.width,c2.height);
    c2Ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    fillPattern = c2Ctx.createPattern(c2, "repeat");
} else {
    fillPattern = drawCtx.createPattern(this.fillImage, "repeat");
}
drawCtx.globalAlpha = 1;
drawCtx.fillStyle = fillPattern;
drawCtx.fillText(this.wrappedText[i], drawpointX, drawpointY + yOffset);`
```

I modified an example off of MSDN that didn't use images or pre-existing canvas. It also did not work on desktop.

`

```
// Create a pattern, offscreen
const patternCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const patternContext = patternCanvas.getContext("2d");

// Give the pattern a width and height of 50
patternCanvas.width = 50;
patternCanvas.height = 50;

// Give the pattern a background color and draw an arc
patternContext.fillStyle = "#fec";
patternContext.fillRect(0, 0, patternCanvas.width, patternCanvas.height);
patternContext.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, 0.5 * Math.PI);
patternContext.stroke();

// Create our primary canvas and fill it with the pattern
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const pattern = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
//ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.font = "40pt Ariel";
ctx.fillText("TEST",50,50);
// Add our primary canvas to the webpage
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

`

Comment: What you've shown should work: https://jsfiddle.net/rdLqfo04/ Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: It did work before Chrome 88. Google addressed a hacking exploit by disabling rendering from dynamic canvas elements.

Comment: Oh, that's so bad. I didn't know of that bug, do you have a reference? You can [workaround it trough a temp <img>](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqbju7st/) but it ought to work as you did, and 88 was a really long time ago, can't believe they left such a big bug in the wild without breaking many web pages.

Comment: Alas, this was the explanation Google's searchbar AI assistant gave me when I asked why it stopped working. Since then I have asked other things and realized it is sometimes wrong. When it doesn't know, it makes stuff up. That said, I have verified my code used to work and have since seen it working on my mobile phone. Browser specific it seems.

Comment: Updating question with some test code.

Comment: Issue 1480200 in chromium: Filltext using canvas as fill pattern no longer renders on desktop chrome/edge